# Problems with grouping factor, data frame, and tapply

Tags: r, statistics, dataframe, tapply

I am very new to R and stats in general and am having trouble getting tapply() to work. I have a data frame with 15 columns and thousands of rows. I made a bunch of logical vectors using something like `y1<-((x>0)&(x<=5))` and similar, where x is a column name in the data frame. These logical vectors were then combined and converted into a grouping factor using factor(). Everything looks to be working fine with this.

The problem is that when I try to use tapply() with `tapply(dataframe, group, sample, size=20)` where `group` is the grouping factor, I get the error: 'arguments must have same length'. When I try `length(dataframe)` I get the number of columns in the data frame (only 15), whereas `length(group)` returns the number of rows (thousands). Is there an error in the way I'm creating my logical vectors and grouping factor?

Here's the output from dput() as Maxim.K suggested: (sorry, it's not very tidy)

```
 structure(list(Lat = c(-90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, 
-90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, -90L, -90L), Lon = -180:-166, 
    Jan = c(2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 
    2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79, 2.79), Feb = c(2.35, 2.35, 
    2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 2.35, 
    2.35, 2.35, 2.35), Mar = c(0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 
    0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49, 0.49
    ), Apr = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    May = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Jun = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Jul = c(0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Aug = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Sep = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Oct = c(1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
    1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 1.75, 
    1.75, 1.75), Nov = c(2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 
    2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77, 2.77), Dec = c(2.65, 
    2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 
    2.65, 2.65, 2.65, 2.65), Ann = c(1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
    1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 1.07, 
    1.07)), .Names = c("Lat", "Lon", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", 
"May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec", "Ann"
), row.names = c(NA, 15L), class = "data.frame")
```

And for group:

15 values from the head (from dput())

```
  structure(c(8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
    8L, 8L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")
```

... and from the tail

```
structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor")
```

I'm trying to take random samples from all 8 categories using tapply() (of size 20).

[edit] Totally unsurprisingly, the problem was not with the question and requirements but with my comprehension. I misread the question; in fact, I was only supposed to sample from one column, not from the entire data frame.

Comment: The question would be easier to answer if you provided some example data. Using `dput(head(yourdata,15))` or something to that extent can be helpful.

Comment: You may want to use `nrow(dataframe)`, which gives the number of rows, instead of `length(dataframe)`,which gives the number of columns, for the comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and it gives back the correct number of rows (i.e. the number of rows in the data frame is the same as in the same as in the grouping factor).

Comment: You've provided input data, alright. But we don't have `group`. Your post is not *completely* reproducible yet. Also, what is the final output you seek? These elements will get your answer quicker.

Comment: @FalseAzure you're getting that error because you are giving a `data.frame` instead of a `vector` to `tapply` function. Reading carefully the the help file you must find: `X an atomic object, typically a vector.` Maybe `aggregate` fits better to this situation.

Comment: Thanks Jilber! Unfortunately I HAVE to use tapply. I'll read over the help file now.

Comment: So this is homework, where a (stupid) requirement is that `tapply` has to be used?

Comment: Yes, and looking at it now it does seem like an odd requirement, unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tapply` can be used here, you just have to add the `group` vector to your `data.frame` and then use `tapply` as in:

```
# Generating a 'group' vector with variability in its values 
# and merging it to the existing data.frame (FOO)
set.seed(1)
FOO$group <- as.factor(sample( 1:8, nrow(FOO), replace=TRUE)) 

# Using tapply
tapply(FOO[,-16], FOO[,16], sample, size=20, replace=TRUE)
```

This may be the answer to your homework.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason I'm still getting the same error, but I should be able to figure it out.